# Fail Rspec Test Case + Integration Testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

```
test "TITLE" do
    products = Product.all
    total_price = products.to_a.sum(&:price)
    expected_total = total_price * 100

    post product_path, price: 500, product: "random"

    assert_template :index
    assert_equal expected_total, products.to_a.map(&:reload).sum(&:price)
end
```

I'm submitting my product randomly and it's working fine. but the price is not display after reload the products. It's display as 0. When I print the value in the form then it's display value in the price field.

Answer (score 0):

On the first line, you don't have any products yet, so `Product.all` will return an empty collection. Therefore `expected_total` will be zero.

If you move this this setup code to after the `post` call then it should pass.

(However, your test is not actually verifying the implementation of the calculation).

Comment: Product.all - Have 5 records.

Comment: In your development database or test database?